# Can I change aspect ratio in Photshop 11 elements and have it maintain integrity for enlargements

Tags: aspect-ratio

I use a Canon T3i and leave my aspect ratio set at 3:2. As I am embarking on 
gallery showings, they want larger and larger images to sell. I have some images that I want to enlarge to 11x14, 16x20 and larger, but as they are, all the online reproduction companies, arbitrarily crop my images, which I do not want.  How can I change the aspect ratio in Photoshop Elements 11 and successfully maintain (not stretch or shrink) the final enlargement?

Linda Hardin

Comment: Not all online printers will arbitrarily crop the images. Some ask you to specify the crop during the order process.

Answer (score 1):

Your image is 3:2, but 5x7 or 8x10 or 11x14 or 16x20 paper, are different aspect ratios, which is a different paper shape, different than your image shape. Square peg in a round hole, so to speak.

So you have to crop the image to the new shape to print it on that shape of paper.

See http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/using/cropping.html

Notice where it says to specify the aspect ratio.

I am not certain of your meaning of "not stretch or shrink"... Did you mean inches or pixels?

Notice that if you also specify a Resolution, it will resample the image to print at that new resolution.  Which is often what you want, for example if you want 8x10 at 300, that is 2400x3000 pixels, so it will resample to 2400x3000 pixels (if you specify the 300 dpi).

Also, other help is with the concept is: http://www.scantips.com/lights/resize.html